# GameObject with Audio File called with FindGameObjectWithTag returns "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: unity, c#

I'm puzzled with this error because in a different file (see below), I'm doing exact same process to an object to enable/disable and works fine. But this new object throws the error, the object has a Script calling an audio file. 
Enabling manually the Object, and playing the game the audio is fine. I hit the check box to disable it and I get the error "Object reference ..."
This audio object is attached to another GameObject which is the character of the game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
    public class carController : MonoBehaviour {

        public float carSpeed;
        public float maxPos = 4.17f;

        Vector3 position;

        public ParticleHit pr;
        public AudioManager cr;
        public Blast cb;

                audioObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("policeAuTag");
                audioObj.SetActive (true);
                cr.carSound.Play ();
```

What am I doing wrong.?
I have closed and reopened unity but nothing. I have changed the tag name but same error.

I have tried also "FindWithTag" and doesn't work.

[image]

What is causing the code to throw errors?

Comment: When I manually check the box for RaceAudio and play the game the audio is coming correctly. But when I uncheck the box for RaceAudio and try to enable it programmatically with the lines here then I get the error. Remember that I have use the same process in a different file and works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is going on?**

It is not `FindGameObjectWithTag` that's returning that error. I guess what you are actually seeing is something like this:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   carController.Start () (at Assets/carController.cs:*line-number*)

Where *line-number* is the line number for `audioObj.SetActive (true);` and this is the actual source of the error.

This kind of error (a `NullReferenceException`) for that specific line can only mean that `audioObj == null`.

**How to fix it?**

So why is `audioObj` assigned `null` by `FindGameObjectWithTag`? There is no documentation entry for that function but [`FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) is close enough:

> Returns a list of **active** GameObjects tagged `tag`.

Emphasis mine; so `FindGameObjectWithTag` returns `null` when no active game object with the specified tag can be found.

So don't deactivate this game object from the editor. Do one of these instead:

- Store a reference to the game object in `carController.Start` or `carController.Awake` and deactivate it immediately. Then use that reference to activate it.
- Deactivate the relevant specific component or components on the game object and activate those.

Comment: Thank you @Eric. So this is what I did. I got the GameObject by tag and use the reference AudioSource to disable it. All this into the Awake. Then into the Start I enabled it and play it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem where I would start a scene with disabled objects and be unable to access them or enable them later on. Start the scene with your object enabled but add `gameObject.SetActive(false);` to the end of your `Start()` method in the last script on your `gameObject`. [Link.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)

In your case, adding `gameObject.SetActive(false);` to `AudioManager` script should do it, but if you have that on other objects and you want them to be active, you should make a new script.

I'm not sure why this happens but I think Unity just doesn't bother loading inactive items at scene start (at least in the Editor).